# With Statements Following Into Functions

Tags: excel, vba

I am in the middle of switching my code over from using .active and .select to something more reliable at the recommendation of the internet. I was wondering about the functionality of with statements, and if they follow into a created function.

```
'---Which way is more proper? 
'1.
Sub TestCase()
  With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("TestWorksheet")
    TestFunction()
  End With
End Sub

Function TestFunction()As Integer
  Dim I As Integer
  I = .cells(1,1)
End function
'--2.
Sub TestCase()
  With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("TestWorksheet")
    TestFunction()
  End With
End Sub

Function TestFunction()As Integer
  Dim I As Integer
  With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("TestWorksheet")
    I = .cells(1,1)
  End With 
End function
```

Comment: Only the last `TestFunction` actually uses the `With....End With` properly. But I imagine you actually want something like `Function TestFunction(ws as Worksheet)...` and then perhaps a `With ws...End With` inside `TestFunction`.

Comment: That said, I highly recommend a read of the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/with-statement).

Comment: That makes sense, thanks a bunch for the response!

Comment: Also, I'd read up on [how to pass arguments to functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/concepts/getting-started/calling-sub-and-function-procedures) (also google around)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, `With` statements do not follow to called functions.  For that functionality, you'd need to pass an argument to the function.  Here's an example that replicates your provided psuedo-code in a valid manner:

```
Sub TestCase()

    MsgBox TestFunction(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("TestWorksheet"))

End Sub

Function TestFunction(ByRef ws As Worksheet) As Double

    With ws
        TestFunction = Val(.Cells(1, 1).Value)
    End With

End Function
```

Note that the Sub is calling the Function and passing the argument which is a worksheet object.  Then in the function you can use the `With` statement on the passed argument.

Answer (score 2):

Most proper (building on @BigBen's very correct comment):

```
Sub TestCase()  
    'Integer variable to catch the return of the function
    Dim somVar as Integer

    'Call the function, pass the worksheet. 
    somVar = TestFunction(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("TestWorksheet"))  

    'Do something with the return
    Debug.print somVar
End Sub

Function TestFunction(ws as Worksheet) As Integer
  Dim I As Integer  
  I = ws.cells(1,1) 

  'Return the integer to the caller 
  TestFunction = I
End function
```